# Cakephp 2.0 can't get or read session view file?

Tags: session, cakephp, view, controller, cakephp-2.x

I'm working to display or read session in view ctp file, but controller showing is session created and read session is also showing in the controller but can't display or read session in view ctp file?

**controller function**

```
var $components = array('Auth','Session','RequestHandler','Email');
$selectedlocation= $_POST['location'];
$this->Session->write('homepagelocation.selectlocation', $selectedlocation);
echo $this->Session->read('homepagelocation.selectlocation');
```

**session reading method in ctp file**

```
echo $this->Session->read('homepagelocation.selectlocation');
```

Comment: "_but can't display or read session_" is not a proper problem description. Even if the problem might be obvious for people that know the CakePHP internals, please always be as specific as possible as to what _exactly_ happens (no output? wrong value being outputted? any errros? etc...), and what you'd expect to happen instead. ps, don't access superglobals directly! Use the request object to [**access post data**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-post-data).

Comment: Check if you load 'Session' component in your AppController

Answer (score 2):

In order to access data from the controller in your view, you need to set the data to the view.

```
var $components = array('Auth','Session','RequestHandler','Email');
$selectedlocation= $_POST['location'];
$this->Session->write('homepagelocation.selectlocation', $selectedlocation);
$this->set('location', $this->Session->read('homepagelocation.selectlocation'));
```

I will ask however, why are you writing data to the session, reading from it and setting that to the view when you already have access to the data you need in `$selectedlocation`?

Answer (score 0):

Ello, mate. I think you $_POST[] does not work this way into your controller, you should try:

```
$this->request->data['location']; //Cake 2.x
$this->data['location']; //Cake 1.3
```

Then you set up the session to the view:

```
$this->set('location', $this->Session->read('homepagelocation.selectlocation'));
```

Now you can print it on your view:

```
echo $location;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/session.html
It is possible to use Session read method in view, please set Session as $helper element in Controller.